# Use of Handler class in Kotlin crashes my android app

Tags: android, kotlin, handler

When i call a method from Handler class, my app can't open in emulator. I tried commenting out the handler parts of the code and app starts normally. I need help in finding mistake in the code or somewhere else.
I am beginner so i was building some basic stuff, a runnable that should make picture visible on random part of the screen, here is the method:

```
fun goKenny(){

    runnable = object : Runnable{
        override fun run() {

            for (kenny in kennyList){
                kenny.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

            var random = Random(8 - 0)
            var randomIndex = random.nextInt()

            kennyList[randomIndex].visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            handler.postDelayed(runnable,300)

        }

    }
    handler.post(runnable)

}
```

Here's the rest of my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private var handler : Handler = Handler()
    private var runnable : Runnable = Runnable {  }
    private var kennyList = tableLayout.children.toList()


    var score = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val sharedPreferences =
        this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.kennygame", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        //sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("High Score",score).apply();

        goKenny()

        object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Time's Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                timeView.text = "TIME'S UP"

                var highScore = sharedPreferences.getInt("High Score", 0)


                val sendHighScore = Intent(applicationContext, Main2Activity::class.java)

                sendHighScore.putExtra("Score", score)
                startActivity(sendHighScore)

            }

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                timeView.text = "TIME: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000
            }


        }.start()


    }
}
```

Error trace:

```
2019-12-12 04:35:48.911 8789-8789/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-12-12 04:35:48.937 8789-8789/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-12-12 04:35:49.305 8789-8789/com.example.kennygame D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-12-12 04:35:49.310 8789-8789/com.example.kennygame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kennygame, PID: 8789
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kennygame/com.example.kennygame.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:655)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
        at com.example.kennygame.MainActivity._$_findCachedViewById(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.example.kennygame.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please add your crash stacktrace.

Comment: there is nothing in my logcat, excuse me if i am mistaking something

Comment: i updated my answer with error trace

Answer (score 0):

Try safe call like this

`handler?.post(runnable)`

UPDATE 1 :

looks like the issue is where you are trying to set visibility of your view. you are getting null object reference.

to verify, try commenting `kenny.visibility = View.INVISIBLE` and `kennyList[randomIndex].visibility = View.INVISIBLE`. It should run successfully after commenting.

UPDATE 2 :

you are using `kennyList` in the for loop which is derived from `tableLayout`. Please try commenting the 'for' loop and let me know if it runs.

UPDATE 3 :

seems problem in `private var kennyList = tableLayout.children.toList()`

try alternative solution like :

```
    private lateinit var kennyList: ArrayList<View>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        for (index in 0 until tableLayout.childCount) {
            val nextChild: View = tableLayout.getChildAt(index)
            kennyList.add(nextChild)
        }
        ...
    }
```

if you still get null object reference, try adding `val tableLayout = findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.tableLayout)` inside `onCreate()` before `for` loop.

Comment: hmm nothing changes, it says: 
Unnecessary safe call on non-null Reciever of type Handler

Comment: can you please provide error-log that you are getting?

Comment: well, i am not getting any errors, that's the problem, app simply won't start

Comment: looks like the issue is where you are trying to set visibility of your view. you are getting null object reference.

Comment: Commented it out, still won't start, still the same error message

Comment: It's sure that the issue is due to a null object reference. you are using `kennyList` in the for loop which is derived from `tableLayout`. Please try commenting the for loop and let me know if it runs.

Comment: app starts fine when i comment loop out,hmmm interesting

Comment: hmm app starts now, works as intended for a lil bit then can't start again, i am too tired for tonight, ill try again tomorrow, thanks for all answers really appreciate it!!

Comment: sure, let me know if any help needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with handler initialization. If you want to construct handler with no-arg constructor you have to do it at later stage of an activity. Lazy initialization would be a simple and best solution for this.

Change your handler initialization like this

```
private val handler : Handler by lazy { Handler() }
```

***NOTE:*** Also check whether you are setting correct visibility for views, because you are setting **`View.INVISIBLE`** in both **for loop** as well as **after for loop** which is redundant or you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: i can't do that
it gives me warning:   
    private var handler : Handler by lazy { Handler() }

Comment: @Veljkoza Sorry for the typo it should be private val handler. Now I have edited it. Check it and let me know if that does not work

Comment: @Veljkoza Are you still getting warning?

Comment: Nope, no warning, but it doesen't change anything, i think that my problem is with this list of ImageViews

Comment: @Veljkoza `for (kenny in kennyList){ kenny.visibility = View.INVISIBLE }` and `kennyList[randomIndex].visibility = View.INVISIBLE` both setting Visibility as **INVISIBLE**. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: ill try again tomorrow, thanks for all answers really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is view not create when to call:
     private var kennyList = tableLayout.children.toList()
tableLayout.children.toList() should called in onCreate()

I refactor your code:

```
private val kennyList: MutableList<View> = mutableListOf()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // init
    kennyList.clear()
    kennyList.addAll(tableLayout.children.toList())

    val sharedPreferences =
        this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.kennygame", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

..................

and

```
fun goKenny(){

    runnable = object : Runnable{
        override fun run() {

            for (kenny in kennyList){
                kenny.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

            var random = Random(8 - 0)
            var randomIndex = random.nextInt()

            //check index
            if (kennyList.indices.contains(randomIndex)) {
                kennyList[randomIndex].visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

            handler.postDelayed(runnable,300)

        }

    }
    handler.post(runnable)

}
```